# How to programmatically access a property of a vba access object/module? like self["property" + i]?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form which has 12 objects named sequentially: object0, object1, object2...
and I would like to do something like a loop to get all the values instead of doing the same thing for each one.

Like:

```
self["object" + i]
```

in a loop where the i is the current number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to Me:

```
Me("Object" & i)
```

When the code is running in the form's module. Or elsewhere:

```
Forms!TheFormName.Controls("Object" & i)
```

Or even

```
Forms![Some Form Name]("Object" & i).Value
```